# Why dont c++ strings work with scanf and printf

Tags: c++, printf, scanf

```
string a;
scanf("%s",&a);
```

gives me an error "unhandled exception :Access violation writing location 0x000EEFFEE" when i run the program and enter the string for expression.

whereas

```
char a[20];
scanf("%s",a);
```

works fine.
Is it only because scanf and printf are inherited from C.
What methods can I use to fix the error.
Is it possible at all to make printf scanf work with c++ strings.

Comment: `scanf()` and `printf()` takes C-strings instead of `std::string`s so for `printf()` you'll want to do `expression.c_str()` and for `scanf()`, you should use a `char` first and then you could convert that to a `std::string`

Comment: %s is for C-style strings.

Comment: Car crash happening mixing c wit c++

Comment: I don't think you should use c_str() function since you don't know the size of the underlying buffer (also it might be const).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath where can i read more about it.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: Modified the question, please review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasons `std::string` can't be used with `printf` is that `std::string` is not a sequence of characters.

The `printf` function expects a sequence of characters terminated by '\0'.

For all we know the `std::string` class could be implemented as:

```
class string
{
  unsigned int capacity;
  unsigned int size;
  char *       p_char_sequence;
};
```

As you can see, the first two items are not characters.

Also, there are not `printf` format specifiers for `std::string`.

In summary, there is no guarantee that the first items in memory of a `std::string` are the characters; it could be a class or structure.

There is a mitigation, the `std::string::c_str()` method.  This method returns a pointer to a C-Style string equivalent of the `std::string` contents.

**Edit 1: `scanf`**
The `scanf` function is more interesting.  The `scanf` function requires a pointer to an array of characters.  There is no guarantee that the first memory address in a `std::string` is a sequence of characters.  See `printf` explanation above.

Also, there is no guarantee that the pointer returned by `std::string::c_str()` is valid for receiving characters.  It could be a temporary area in memory, used only for output.  Thus it can't be used for `scanf`.

The `scanf` function will write characters to the array locations *until the input is terminated.*  This means that if you allocate space for 3 characters and the User inputs 20 characters, the `scanf` function will start overwriting the *array* and write to whatever follows it.  This could trigger a system error (such as writing outside your program's area) or write to hardware addresses.  This is why most references say to use `fscanf` where a limit or capacity can be specified.

Comment: Thanks! This clears up a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to use c-strings with scanf not c++ strings.  Redeclare expression as char expression[N]; where N is a large enough number of characters to store the entire word.  Also you would not need the & infront of it when you pass it to scanf since arrays are converted to pointers automatically.

An even better approach would be to replace scanf with `cin >> expression;`  And replace printf with `cout << expression;`  that is the way to do it in c++.

Comment: I just wanted to try out printf and scanf for SPOJ problems since i read that they are faster than cin and cout.

Comment: cin and cout are MUCH faster than printf and scanf. No comparison.

Comment: @nicomp actually, with sync_with_stdio turned on (the default), they tend to be much slower. At least with MSVC.

Comment: They should be because printf has to determine what data types it is reading at run time by parsing the format string.  When you use c++ streams everything is setup when the program is compiled.

Comment: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/5217, here it shows how the stdio functions are faster than cout, cin

Comment: I edited the question, please delete this answer.